# Android CTS is showing ShellCommandUnresponsiveException on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, cts

I am running Android CTS Android Test Plan on an emulator running on Android 2.2.

But most of the test cases are showing timeout and the error shows com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException.

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Set shell command time out to 5 minutes (instead of 5 seconds:-))

```
diff --git a/tools/host/src/com/android/cts/TestDevice.java b/tools/host/src/com/android/cts/TestDevice.java
index 65ff969..b8578bc 100644
--- a/tools/host/src/com/android/cts/TestDevice.java
+++ b/tools/host/src/com/android/cts/TestDevice.java
@@ -18,6 +18,7 @@ package com.android.cts;

 import com.android.ddmlib.Client;
 import com.android.ddmlib.ClientData;
+import com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences;
 import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
 import com.android.ddmlib.IShellOutputReceiver;
 import com.android.ddmlib.MultiLineReceiver;
@@ -143,6 +144,7 @@ public class TestDevice implements DeviceObserver {
         mDeviceInfo = new DeviceParameterCollector();
         mPackageActionTimer = new PackageActionTimer();
         mObjectSync = new ObjectSync();
+        DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(300000);
     }
```

Comment: It was difficult to read the patch. Please consider formatting it. Apart from that, your solution seems to work well for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more notes for newbies like me:

1. download android source
2. apply the patch, and build with command: `make cts`
3. copy the newly built file `cts.jar` to replace the stock one.

This fix CTS timeout problem because some adb commands needs more than 20 seconds to return on my MotoA953 device (one of these is `am instrument -w -e bundle true android.tests.devicesetup/android.tests.getinfo.DeviceInfoInstrument`).